# Spring 4.0.1 + Quartz 1.5.2

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a cron job using Spring 4.0.1 and Quartz 1.5.2, but I get an error when I run it on my server. the error shows:

`SEVERE: Servlet [appServlet] in web application [/SpringRestSample] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)`

my xml configuration is :

```
<beans:bean id="removeExpiredSessionFetchJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jobClass">
        <beans:value>com.iris.spring.rest.model.RemoveExpiredSessionFetchJob</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="removeExpiredSessionTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

    <beans:property name="jobDetail">
        <beans:ref bean="removeExpiredSessionFetchJob" />
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="cronExpression">
        <!--  <value>0 0/55 * * * ?</value> -->
        <beans:value>0 */1 * * * ?</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="triggers">

        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="removeExpiredSessionTrigger" />

         </beans:list>

    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

my pom.xml is :

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`quartz` / `quartz` is some old Quartz version, which according to [Maven Repository webpage](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/quartz/quartz) was moved to `org.quartz-scheduler` / `quartz`. So the correct Quartz dependency, which contains the class `JobDetailImpl`, which is missing according to your stack trace should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: when i changed to 2.2.1 then compiler shows : **The import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext cannot be resolved, The import org.quartz.JobExecutionException cannot be resolved** .. How can i resolve this problem? the jar already downloaded in maven repository.

Comment: @MarvelJohn That's strange, because when I look at the contents of the dependency in IntelliJ, I can see those classes there. Is this an error in the IDE (in that case try some sort of refresh) or does it happen when you run `mvn clean compile` also?